# How can i put the css for all specific php pages

Tags: php

My folders are here: [image]

In my header.php there is this code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

In the index.php i can include like this:

```
include('header.php')
```

I can reach style.css there is no problem.

But, in the product/product.php

```
include('../header.php')
```

I can not reach style.css
I can reach the header.php but i can not reach style.css. Because in the header.php,  this include code seems that style.css is in the product/style.css,  but my style.css is in home folder. How can i reach? Can u help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What do you mean by "can not reach"? What error are you getting?

Comment: `href="/style.css">` ? This path is an URL, not a path from executing script.

Comment: Use absolut path: `href="/style.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple the browsers try to request the file relative to the current directory, so just need to add / in the begging of the HREF to make sure you are referring to a file that is in the root.

Solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: When i change the href, any page does not see the style.css

Comment: @Berkay Why it won't "see" the css? in such case just add there valid path starting with slash and it **must** "see" it. Of course if style.css is in some subfolder, you need add it in the path.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  this code is in the header.php,   if i include the header.php on the product/product.php i can not reach style.css,   but in the index.php i can reach the style.css with including header.php

Comment: If i change href="../style.css" this time i can reach style.css in the product/product.php but i can not reach style.css in index.php

Comment: @Berkay What is the URL to reach the css file 'https://example.com/style.css" ? What is the URL of the index page and product page ? URL are different than filepath.

Comment: I fixed that, if i change /style.css it goes to localhost. Thank you, my folder is localhost/site/style.css , i forgot that. :)  Thank you guys.